# Validation Error on app upload

Tags: webdeploy, shiny-server

I want to deploy my app to the shiny cloud server using Rstudio 3.2.5. When I do I get this error:

> Error: HTTP 400 POST https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/ Validation Error

How do I resolve this?

```
install.packages('rsconnect')
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='name', token='token'",  secret="secret")
rsconnect::deployApp('C:/Users/path/of/R/app')
or 
shinyapps::deployApp("C:\\Users\\path\\of\\R\\app")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using more than 4 letter word for my app. But the issue was more due to firewall of my company I guess. I disconnected from VPN and tried deploying using public wireless and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This one was bugging me for a while today. Turns out the app name has criteria (these aren't mentioned if you just deploy via the button or command)...

App name needs to be minimum 4 characters with no spaces. Try a new name for the app and see if that works.